# Trail Mix Packaging problem part 1.2

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so here is my [original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044904/linear-equations-with-fractions?noredirect=1#comment6277029_3044904)  from a book I am trying to learn.  I can figure out the first part of the answer from @YukiJ however, I am unable to determine how the second part of the calculation was achieved:

> First Part: You can solve the problem with any algorithm for a system of linear equations. If you want to calculate the solution by hand then things will get somewhat easier if you multiply each equation with 15 to remove the denominators:

$$7b+6s+2f=5700(raisins)$$
$$6b+4s+5f=7500(peanuts)$$
$$2b+5s+8f=9300(chocolate)$$

> Second part: By adding the -$\frac{6}{7}$ -multiple of the first equation to the second and the −$\frac{2}{7}$ -multiple of the first equation to the third equation you obtain the following system:

$$Eq.one.\  7b+6s+2f=5700\ (raisins)$$
$$Eq.two.\  −\frac{8}{7}s+\frac{23}{7}f=\frac{18300}{7}\ (peanuts)$$
$$Eq.three.\  \frac{23}{7}s+\frac{52}{7}f=\frac{53700}{7}\ (chocolate)$$

I can not work out how the answer came out to 23 and 52 yet, this is my interpretation.

$$Att.one.Eq.two.\  \frac{6 * -6}{7}b\  + \frac{4 * -6}{7}s\  + \frac{5 * -6}{7}f\  = \frac{18300}{7} \ *$$

Could someone please break down the **second part** of the equation so I can understand it?  $\ *$ Definitely unsure how this value was attained.

Secondly, should I keep reading this book or is there another book that can help me with basic linear algebra that, would be more appropriate?  Please base this second question after looking at the book attached to the **"original problem"** link above.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: New 2nd line: for column b : $6 - 6*7/7 = 0$. For column s: $4 - 36/7 = -8/7$ For column f $5 -12/7 = 23/7$ etc.

Comment: OK, I think I am starting to get it. Here is equation with the co-ordinates: $$Eq2. \frac{6_{21} - 6_{12}}{7_{11}} + \frac{4_{22} * 7_{11} - 6_{12} * 6_{21}}{7_{11}} + \frac{5_{23} * 7_{11} - 6_{12} * 2_{13}}{7_{11}}$$

Comment: The answer to the third equation does appear to be correct. $$\frac{23}{7}s+\frac{52}{7}f=\frac{53000}{7}\ (chocolate)$$  I get 53000 compared with 53700. Btw @damien you explanation seems to give the right answer if you would like to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you for proposing. I have no time now to edit a clean answer. Good if I could help you

Comment: It is ok, I will ask another question showing my workings.  Thank you for helping.